Is try-with-resources ever possible for scheduleAtFixedRate?
I use scheduleAtFixedRate for a task that need to be repeated every 500 ms:
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass() {
        int delay = 500;
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
              ...
        }, delay, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

IntelliJ suggests that I should use try-with-resources clause for my executor but if I do that then it will shut it down soon after initializing it. So my question, is it ever possible or useful to use try-with-resources on a scheduleAtFixedRate service? And how do I get rid of Intellij warning properly (without suppressing it)?

ScheduledExecutorService isn't closeable. How are you using this with try-with-Resources in the first place?

ScheduledExecutorService is AutoCloseable. So it could technically be used in a try-with-resources. But it does not really make sense. The close method is not called until all submitted tasks have completed/failed. But a scheduleAtFixedRate does not terminate on its own, it runs indefinitely.

You do need to keep that reference to your ScheduledExecutorService somewhere, not just in your local variable executor. At some point you’ll need to gracefully shut it down, before your app ends. Otherwise its backing pool of threads may run indefinitely, like zombies.  ‍♂️‍♀️

@ElliottFrisch Note Java 19 made ExecutorService extend AutoCloseable, and ScheduledExecutorService extends ExecutorService.

@BasilBourque in my case I don't need to keep reference to ScheduledExecutorService because it needs to keep running until the user quits the app.

Re: "And how do I get rid of Intellij warning properly (without suppressing it)?": Why don't you want to suppress it?

Because suppressing usually implies that the author is too lazy to fix it the proper way. Intellij warnings usually have a proper solution. If there is no proper solution then I should file a bug report with intellij. But first I wanted to ask here.

@SaeidNourian "suppressing usually implies that the author is too lazy to fix it the proper way" - No, warnings can have false positives.

@SaeidNourianm You do need to shutdown that executor service before your app ends. Please learn from my experience and that of others. The backing thread pool can outlive your app.  To shutdown, use boilerplate code given in the Javadoc, or call similar implementation in the close command.

Your class creates a ScheduledExecutorService in its constructor, lets it do some work forever, and never tells it to stop. It's using a local variable so that goes out of scope once the constructor ends. Either garbage collection causes the ScheduledExecutorService to stop its work, or it will never stop and you have no way to stop it because all references are gone. I don't really know which is the case.
To solve both possibilities, as well as your IDE complaining, you can turn it into a field and close it when you're done with the class by making that AutoCloseable as well:
public class MyClass implements AutoCloseable {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;

    private MyClass() {
        int delay = 500;
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
              ...
        }, delay, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void close() {
        executor.close();
    }
}

Of course, now you have to close instances of MyClass, so you're effectively shifting the problem.
Another option is similar. However, instead of implementing AutoCloseable you can make the closing more implicit by using Cleaner to close the ScheduledExecutorService when the MyClass instance is cleaned up as part of garbage collection. (Note that Cleaner can be used in the first option as well by replacing executor.close() with calling  clean() on the Cleaner.Cleanable you get). Note that your IDE might still complain because it may not see that the ScheduledExecutorService is closed by the Cleaner. Annotating the variable (or if needed the constructor) with @SupressWarnings("resource") can make your IDE shut up.

Thanks, I already knew that I could convert my executor to a field and make a call to it to avoid warnings but that's unnecessary code in my app. My app exits with a call to System.exit() so it's guaranteed to kill all background threads. An explicit call to close in redundant. I put great effort in making coding free of unnecessary codes and avoid adding codes that serves no practical purpose. I take it from your answer and others that try-with-resource is impossible to use directly on newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor so I will file a bug report with Intellij.

You can try, but I don't think that bug will be accepted (note: I'm not affiliated with IntelliJ). I see it more as a false positive. You know that the ScheduledExecutorService will be closed when the app exits, but IntelliJ (or any other IDE) cannot know this. It just sees a resource (which ScheduledExecutorService is since it implements AutoCloseable) that is never closed. There are bound to be cases where it is desirable to use try-with-resources with ScheduledExecutorService.
